# Problem with SpatialFPStruct , RPR fom, netn2_2010 FOM. How should it be implemented?

Tags: java, high-level-architecture, dis

I am trying to code a netn2_2010 FOM federate. I did some structures:
WorldLocationStruct, WorldLocationStructEncoder, SpatialFPStruct , SpatialFPStructEncoder and others. My problem is, my WorldLocationStruct has 3 attributes X,Y and Z which are the first 3 attributes to be added into SpatialFPStruct encoder. So, when I update spatial attributes my first world location attribute is not being treated as an X position and I have no idea why this is happening. When I set my coordinates I noticed that my Y attribute coordinate is being treated as X coordinate and my Z coordinate attribute is being treated as Y coordinate.

The log is returning this message:
Spatial, [49:***01000000 00000000*** 414f9b8d 31f27235 c14fba2b a3d7f715 c142ee80 cc867855 00000000 3f0aa32c bf0b9343 bf8e15f1 00]

Wasn`t the bolded text supposed to be my X coordinate?

```
WorldLocationStruct: https://pastebin.com/3eqxd6UC 
WorldLocationStructEncoder: https://pastebin.com/1xb9W180 
SpatialFPStruct: https://pastebin.com/fZaHiJHS 
SpatialFPStructEncoder: https://pastebin.com/Dhk7eQPi
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific when you say you update the attributes? What does the federate code look like that updates? What about the subscribing federate?

Comment: Here goes my code with aircraft implemantation https://pastebin.com/9h7WDcSC 
In this way I am doing the aircraft is being marked in a region close to the right one but with a very bad precision.

Comment: [Falo Português] Please contact me.You can see my address in my profile here. I'm in a big project using SISO FOM and need some info exchange. https://github.com/icemagno/virt